# How to prevent clients from navigating my GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql

Okay so this is a theoretical question so I don't have any code to show. Consider that I have GraphQL types like so:

```
type A {
field1: String!
field2: B!
} 

type B {
fieldB1: Int!
fieldB2: C!
aRef: A!
}

type C {
fieldC1: Boolean!
fieldC2: D!
bRef: B!
}
```

So my question is that given a query which can enter some point in my graph. How do I prevent clients from travelling that graph to an arbitrary depth and asking for way more data than they should. Is there any way to restrict how many relationships a query can navigate ? Can I control this on server side ? How do I stop queries which can navigate from A to B to C to D and so forth without restriction ?

Comment: Yes, you can make your server accept only queries from a whitelist, or reject queries from a blacklist, and also you can do it dynamically based on nesting depth or really anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current GraphQL specification (which can be read https://spec.graphql.org/) does not have depth limit features defined as part of the spec.

However, many GraphQL server implementations support a depth limit to prevent cyclic queries - or there are packages which does this (for example [graphql-depth-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-depth-limit) for NodeJS)

The keyword you want to search for is *depth limit* for GraphQL.

A good read is an article [GraphQL Cyclic Queries and Depth Limiting](https://escape.tech/blog/cyclic-queries-and-depth-limit/):

> Many GraphQL implementations provide a specific parameter that you just have to set to a given value so that queries that exceed this depth level are automatically ignored by the GraphQL engine, without even starting the evaluation.
>
> There are several ways to proceed, depending on the GraphQL engine you use:
>
> Apollo, Express GraphQL, GraphQL Node

Comment: Cheers that made it much simpler to find.